# How to prevent decimal values entering in db?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

-- Table: Cabin

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cabin (
cabinID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
cabinType VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
cabinDescription VARCHAR(255),
pricePerNight BIGINT NOT NULL,
pricePerWeek DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
photo VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Cabin (cabinType, cabinDescription, pricePerNight, pricePerWeek, photo)
VALUES ('test cabin 2', 'test cabin with invalid data', 100.87, 625, 'insertCabin1.jpg');
```

-- **This insertion should generate an error because the pricePerNight is a decimal number**

I am using myphpadmin and it is successfully inserted into the database with rounded figure 101.
so how can i modify column to prevent decimal values entering into database?
Please guide, thanks in advance.

I should get error when inserting decimal values in pricePerNight column like 100.87
I also tried CHECK constraint like this
pricePerNight BIGINT(10) NOT NULL CHECK (pricePerNight >= 0 AND pricePerNight % 1 = 0)
but it still gets inserted in db.

Comment: @akina my reading of the question is OP wants to reject the insert if the value contains decimals. I don't think this is possible since implicit conversion with rounding to integer has happened before it can be trapped in a check constraint or before insert trigger (the new.value is already implicitly converted).

Comment: @P.Salmon Agreed, comment removed.

Comment: Is there a reason why you wish to retain the integer datatype for pricePerNight when you can catch any value with decimal values if the datatype is decimal?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert rounded value instead of entered one then modify your query to

```
INSERT INTO Cabin (cabinType, cabinDescription, pricePerNight, pricePerWeek, photo)
VALUES (?, ?, ROUND(?), ?, ?);
```

After parameters substitution this will be

```
INSERT INTO Cabin (cabinType, cabinDescription, pricePerNight, pricePerWeek, photo)
VALUES ('test cabin 2', 'test cabin with invalid data', ROUND(100.87), 625, 'insertCabin1.jpg');
```

The function will return 101 instead of entered 100.87, and the error won't occur.

Comment: but i don't want 101 , it should only accept whole number that I enter, in case 100.87 , it should give error.

Comment: If you need to save decimal value which is entered then you **must** alter the column datatype. Noway to save decimal value into integer-type column. *it should give error.* Alter SQL Server mode to `strict`.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Cabin (
cabinID BIGINT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
cabinType VARCHAR(150) NOT NULL,
cabinDescription VARCHAR(255),
pricePerNight DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL CHECK (pricePerNight=ROUND(pricePerNight)),

pricePerWeek DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL,
photo VARCHAR(50)
);

-- valid data, because 101 = ROUND(101)
INSERT INTO Cabin (cabinType, cabinDescription, pricePerNight, pricePerWeek, photo)
VALUES ('test cabin 1', 'test cabin with valid data', 101, 625, 'insertCabin1.jpg');

-- invalid data, because 100.87 <> ROUND(100.87)
INSERT INTO Cabin (cabinType, cabinDescription, pricePerNight, pricePerWeek, photo)
VALUES ('test cabin 2', 'test cabin with invalid data', 100.87, 625, 'insertCabin2.jpg');
```

I wouldn't think BIGINT is needed for the price per night. That cabin must be very posh!

Comment: I want to reject the insert if the value contains decimals.

Comment: I understand that. The solution I show above will do that (it requires MySQL 8.0.16 or later). Try it!